# Can I insert multiple audio files in my HTML document which play on loop

Tags: html, audio

I want to insert more than one audio file on my website but they all should have a single icon. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "autoplay" attribute from the "audio" tags and use javascript:         http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio

The method "ended" is called when one "audio" tag finishes:

```
<audio ... ended="nextAudioNode.play();">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp